# Meteor js - почему insert добавляет максимум 1000 строк?

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
for(i=0; i<10000; i++)
  Gnomy.insert({name: names[_.random(0, 12)], age: _.random(20, 30), size: _.random(50, 100)});
```

В итоге создаётся лишь 1000 (чуть больше). Почему?

На старом компе просто жуткие глюки. И выводился список не сразу, а поэтапно, достаточно долго, можно ли как то всё это ускорить? Вообще на сколько это всё будет критично для большого сайта?

Comment: Я так понимаю это ограничение ресурсов моего компьютера влияют на скорость обработки запроса, в то время как в хроме имеется ограничение на время выполнения сценария. Всё равно, хочется подробностей, почему всё так долго?

Comment: Выполняй код на сервера через метод

Comment: Ок, спасибо! А почему выводится список из 2000 так долго в браузере?

Comment: Долго это сколько? И что на клиенте используете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert производимый на стороне клиента в цикле for запустит процесс поэтапного добавления документов в коллекцию, при этом, судя по моим догадкам, срабатывает лимит по времени на выполнения сценария браузера, и процесс прерывается по достижению данного лимита. Так же следует учесть, что поэтапность означает, что перед этапом 2 должен завершится этап 1, по этому можно видеть в консоли, запуская команды Gnomy.find().count(), как плавно растёт число.

Эта же плавность происходит и на стороне сервера, если запустить цикл for с командой Gnomy.insert({...}), но при этом цифра документов всё же достигает заданной.

Можно ускорить процесс, используя пакетную вставку, которая реализована и доступна в пакете [mikowals:batch-insert](https://atmospherejs.com/mikowals/batch-insert).

Подробнее о данном вопросе рассматривается в [статье](https://blog.meteor.com/inserting-50000-documents-into-a-collection-slow-fast-and-fastest-1ec00d20bb23) официального блога Meteor.

Приятной работы!